# NOVO Theme change photos in the banner

Tags: store, banner

Can anyone help me finding the way to change the photos I have on a photo banner in my shop? I am using NOVO theme.
I know that the banner is pulling the photos from somewhere, but I cannot find from where.
It doesn't seem like this has nothing to do with the Woocommerce settings either.
I already went through the documents of the theme and I couldn't find any explanation about this.
Thank you so much

I already read the documents and went through the customization but cannot find where to change the photos that are showing now.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am using NOVO theme in my website. The shop, has a photo banner on the top that I would like to edit, but I can't because the shop is not a page, so I don't see the page edit option on the top of my wordpress. Thank you